# Compare columns common in two dataframes and copy row if the column name matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am new to Pandas and I have this below query, I have two dataframes df1 & df2
the df1 is an empty dataframe with 3 columns and df2 has 5 columns with some records.

Df1 Ex below

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

Df2 Ex

| A | B | D | C | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

If the column name matches, I want to copy all rows from df2 to df1.
like below

DF1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |

it can be df1 or it can be a new data frame. Kindly help me with this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general solution for filter of intersection of columns between both DataFrames use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
Df1 = Df2.reindex(Df1.columns.intersection(Df2.columns, sort=False), axis=1)
```

If always exist all columns from `Df1.columns` in `Df2.columns` use:

```
Df1 = Df2[Df1.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to initialize an empty DataFrame, you can directly use:

```
df1 = df2[df1.columns].copy()
```